# How to set a symbolic breakpoint in Xcode on a WebKit function

Tags: ios, xcode, webkit, breakpoints

In order to triage an issue I am trying to set a symbolic breakpoint in Xcode on a c++ function, but it never hits (I tried both live device and simulator, using a debug build).

I am using the function name as listed in a symbolicated stack trace. For example:

> WebKit::WebLoaderStrategy::loadResourceSynchronously+

Is there any trick to get this to work?

While I think it is possible to build WebKit I don't think this would be of use since I can't rebuild iOS with my version of WebKit. But I assumed at least the symbols would match up with that is in stack traces of crash logs (and also with the source of WebKit on Git).

Update, if I just enter in "loadResourceSynchronously" it automatically found the following symbols: (cut and paste doesn't work for some reason, so will use an image)

[image]

This seems to indicate the symbols are understood by Xcode. However I never see any of them being called. Based on the stack traces I am seeing for crashes I am pretty sure they should be called.

Comment: you should post the stacktrace that led you to the conclusion one of these is called.